# Simple text not showing for PDF fin Acrobat but works in Firefox and MicrosftEdge

Tags: c++, pdf

update: I have updated the corrected code and it works 100%

I have written a program that generates a word search and it works perfectly. I want to output to a PDF file without any 3rd party software. I will post the c++ routine and the generated PDF file.
Why does this work in browsers and Acrobat? It opens but the page is blank.
The PDF file is very simple.

```
void SavePdf(const string& fileName, vector<vector<char>>& board, vector<string>& words)
{
    const string eol = "\r\n";
    const string version = "1.0";
    const auto heightPerLine = 20;
    const auto topMargin = 300;
    const auto pages = 1;

    const auto width = 800;
    const auto height = max(board.size() * heightPerLine + topMargin, 1200ull);

    vector<unsigned long long>offsets;

    stringstream pdfBuffer;
    pdfBuffer <<
        "%PDF-" << version << eol << eol;

    offsets.push_back(pdfBuffer.tellp());
    pdfBuffer <<
        "1 0 obj" << eol <<
        "<< /Type /Catalog" << eol <<
        "/Pages 2 0 R" << eol <<
        ">>" << eol <<
        "endobj" << eol << eol;

    offsets.push_back(pdfBuffer.tellp());
    pdfBuffer <<
        "2 0 obj" << eol <<
        "<< /Type /Pages" << eol <<
        "/Kids[3 0 R]" << eol <<
        "/Count " << pages << eol <<
        "/MediaBox[0 0 " << width << ' ' << height << "]" << eol <<
        ">>" << eol <<
        "endobj" << eol << eol;

    offsets.push_back( pdfBuffer.tellp());
    pdfBuffer <<
        "3 0 obj" << eol <<
        "<< /Type /Page" << eol <<
        "/Parent 2 0 R" << eol <<
        "/Resources" << eol <<
        "<< /Font" << eol <<
        "<< /F1" << eol <<
        "<< /Type /Font" << eol <<
        "/Subtype /Type1" << eol <<
        "/BaseFont /Courier" << eol <<
        ">>" << eol <<
        ">>" << eol <<
        ">>" << eol <<
        "/Contents 4 0 R" << eol <<
        ">>" << eol <<
        "endobj" << eol << eol;

    stringstream boardStream;
    auto yPos = height - 30;
    const auto xPos = (width - static_cast<double>(board[0].size()) * 2 * 6.5) / 2;
    for (auto& row : board)
    {
        boardStream <<
            "BT" << eol <<
            "/F1 12 Tf" << eol <<
            xPos << ' ' << yPos << " Td" << eol << '(';
        for (auto& c : row)
            boardStream << c << ' ';
        boardStream << ") Tj" << eol <<
            "ET" << eol;

        yPos -= heightPerLine;
    }

    offsets.push_back( pdfBuffer.tellp());
    pdfBuffer <<
        "4 0 obj" << eol <<
        "<< /Length " << static_cast<int>(boardStream.tellp()) << " >>" << eol <<
        "stream" << eol <<
        boardStream.str() << eol <<
        "endstream" << eol <<
        "endobj" << eol << eol;

    auto xRefOffset = pdfBuffer.tellp();
    pdfBuffer <<
        "xref" << eol <<
        "0 " << offsets.size() + 1 << eol <<
        "0000000000 65535 f" << eol;

    for (auto& offset : offsets)
        pdfBuffer << setw(10) << setfill('0') << offset << ' ' << setw(5) << 0 << " n" << eol;
    pdfBuffer << eol;

    pdfBuffer <<
        "trailer" << eol <<
        "<<" << eol <<
        "/Root 1 0 R" << eol <<
        "/Size " << offsets.size() + 1 << eol <<
        ">>" << eol << eol <<
        "startxref" << eol <<
        xRefOffset << eol <<
        "%%EOF" << eol;

    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open(fileName, ofstream::out | ofstream::trunc | ofstream::binary);
    if (outFile.is_open())
    {
        outFile << pdfBuffer.str();
        outFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error creating output file " << fileName << '.' << endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

The generated PDF file....

```
%PDF-1.0

1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Pages 2 0 R
>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
/Kids[3 0 R]
/Count 1
/MediaBox[0 0 800 1200]
>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<< /Type /Page
/Parent 2 0 R
/Resources
<< /Font
<< /F1
<< /Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/BaseFont /Courier
>>
>>
>>
/Contents 4 0 R
>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<< /Length 1643 >>
stream
BT
/F1 12 Tf
250.5 1170 Td
(V A R I C E L L A R S Y S Y T N M T V N C O I ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 12 Tf
250.5 1150 Td
(A S E T A I R A V U E L T S B E U A A F I C F ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 12 Tf
250.5 1130 Td
(P N O I T A I R A V C L S V G J V S R H W V S ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 12 Tf
250.5 1110 Td
(H Y E V A R I A S P I A I A S M A E I V G A Z ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 12 Tf
250.5 1090 Td
(V A R I A N T S C Q R N N R U D R S C A P R U ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 12 Tf
250.5 1070 Td
(V G N I T A I R A V A O O I O I I O O R V I E ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 12 Tf
250.5 1050 Td
(L A N O I T A I R A V I I C L O C C S I B E T ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 12 Tf
250.5 1030 Td
(B K K E T A I R A V K T T E L C O I I C Y D A ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 12 Tf
250.5 1010 Td
(U S N O I T A I R A V A A L E I L R T O M N G ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 12 Tf
250.5 990 Td
(V A R I A T E D O B F I I L C R O A I T O E E ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 12 Tf
250.5 970 Td
(E V I T A I R A V R T R R A I A U V E O T S I ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 12 Tf
250.5 950 Td
(G S H V A R I C E L L A A T R V R O S M O S R ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 12 Tf
250.5 930 Td
(T S I N O I T A I R A V V E A A E P F I C E A ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 12 Tf
250.5 910 Td
(F B V A R I C E L L A S J R V R D A S E I S V ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 12 Tf
250.5 890 Td
(V A R I C E L L O I D M D E I R A V F S R D W ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 12 Tf
250.5 870 Td
(U T X S E L E C O C I R A V D G S Z R K A K W ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 12 Tf
250.5 850 Td
(F K V A R I C O L O R E D V Q B Q I E X V A R ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 12 Tf
250.5 830 Td
(Y L D E I R A V A R I C O S E D J Z F G K X O ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 12 Tf
250.5 810 Td
(P S I S O C I R A V A R I C O S I T Y W O J S ) Tj
ET

endstream
endobj

xref
0 5
0000000000 65535 f
0000000012 00000 n
0000000068 00000 n
0000000157 00000 n
0000000323 00000 n

trailer
<<
/Root 1 0 R
/Size 5
>>

startxref
2026
%%EOF
```

Comment: Your pdf format is not right.

Comment: *The generated PDF file....* -- That is not the file.  That is a text rendition of the file.  To diagnose PDF errors, you need to somehow gives us the exact file.

Comment: @D.Sikilai  what part is wrong with my PDF format

Comment: If you copy and paste the text into a text editor and save it as .pdf you will have the file. 
Is there a way to attach a PDF file in stackexchange?

Comment: Did you check if those numbers in the `xref` section actually match the offset within the file where the object starts?  Also copying and pasting text and then getting a valid PDF is not guaranteed to get you the exact file -- PDF is a "binary" format, not a text format.  A better option is for you post the entire code (not just the function), so that the file can be generated locally.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have added a link to the file

Comment: All you needed to do is post a 1 line `main` program that calls the function, [just like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/628fd574931dbe7a) . External links to other sites (other than compiler sites, godbolt, etc.) are discouraged here.  Just to let you know, that file generated by the code at the link is corrupted according to Nitro PDF.

Comment: One thing -- your `xref` offsets seem to be off due to the carriage returns.  I suggest you get a binary editor and verify those objects start at those cross reference numbers.   Second, PDF files usually have some sort of binary short leader text after the `PDF-1.0`, and you are missing this.  Last, Acrobat (and Nitro PDF) detects that the file is corrupted, and attempts to "correct" it -- web browsers are not the tool to use to determine if the file is corrupt, as the tool itself is probably trying to correct your mistakes behind the scenes.

Comment: *"If you copy and paste the text into a text editor and save it as .pdf you will have the file."* - which line endings do you assume? With the wrong choice thereof cross references are broken. *"Is there a way to attach a PDF file in stackexchange?"* - not directly. Usually you use some file sharing service (like public Google drive or Dropbox shares, please not a service that drowns a Downloader in ads) to publish the file and share the url here.

Comment: WIndows eol  cr lf
I also added a URL to the pdf download

Comment: As @PaulMcKenzie already mentions, your cross reference entries and the **startxref** offset are wrong. Similarly the size of the stream is incorrect. Furthermore, in your cross references you drop object 4, `0 4` means *starting from 0 there are 4 entries*, i.e. only the entries for 0, 1, 2, and 3 are seen, your entry for object 4 is ignored. Similarly your **Size** entry in the **trailer** is too small by 1. Correcting all those problems the result shows fine on Acrobat Reader, too.

Comment: @PaulBaxter -- Again need to stress this -- if you are going to create PDF files from scratch, having a good binary editor is essential, almost mandatory.  There is no way you could verify whether your cross reference numbers are correct by visually looking at the file's contents.  That's why originally the file's contents you posted in the text window were useless to diagnose the problem, and we either needed the actual file to verify the offsets and other aspects, or you give us the code to generate a sample file.

Comment: @PaulBaxter -- Also, I forget to mention -- `outFile.open(fileName, ofstream::out | ofstream::trunc);` -- This file should be opened in binary mode, not text mode.  I believe this is the genesis of the problem, and that is the erroneous belief that PDF is a text-based format.  Various objects and data within the PDF are text, yes, but the file in totality needs to be treated as a binary file.

Comment: @mkl -- Can you post your findings and your corrections as an answer?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie *"Can you post your findings and your corrections as an answer?"* - Ok. I refrained as you first correctly mentioned the issue of incorrect offsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @PaulMcKenzie already mentioned your cross reference entries and the **startxref** offset are wrong. Similarly the **Length** of the stream is incorrect.

Most likely this is due to you calculating those offsets and lengths from positions in your `stringstream pdfBuffer`, ignoring that a single character might become multiple bytes when writing the character to a file, in particular `endl` most likely will add only a '\n' character in `pdfBuffer` which becomes the two bytes 0x0d 0x0a in the file on Windows.

Using a hex editor I fixed that in your file by replacing the stream dictionary

```
   << /Length 1995 >>
```

by

```
   << /Length 2107 >>
```

and your cross reference table entries

```
0000000010 00000 n
0000000072 00000 n
0000000176 00000 n
0000000446 00000 n
```

by

```
0000000012 00000 n
0000000080 00000 n
0000000192 00000 n
0000000478 00000 n
```

and finally the **startxref** entry

```
startxref
2502
```

by

```
startxref
2654
```

Furthermore, in your cross references you drop object 4, `0 4` means starting from object 0 there are entries for 4 objects, i.e. only the entries for 0, 1, 2, and 3 are seen, your entry for object 4 is ignored. Similarly your Size entry in the trailer is too small by 1.

I fixed that in your file by further replacing

```
xref
0 4
```

by

```
xref
0 5
```

and in the trailer

```
   /Size 4
```

by

```
   /Size 5
```

After these changes Acrobat Reader also shows your letter grid properly. Furthermore, Adobe Reader does not have to repair the file, so it does not ask whether it should save the changes upon closing anymore.

Comment: Just to add to the @OP -- if you manually edit a PDF file using a hex editor, make sure the editor is initially in overwrite mode, not insert mode.  If you insert (or remove) characters from a PDF file that shifts the contents left or right, this will affect the cross reference numbers, stream sizes, etc.  and you will then have to recalculate all of those numbers, otherwise the PDF file will be corrupted.  Overwriting the PDF data is fine, so long as you have room for the overwrites without moving the contents around.